# Negative grayscale values - Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, grayscale

I am using the following code to get the R,G,B values for a grayscale image(they all will be the same)
But the output gives me negative values.

Why is this so? I am totally confused.

```
for (int i=0;i<bb.getWidth();i++){
                            for (int j=0;j<bb.getHeight();j++){
                                    long temp=bb.getPixel(i, j);
                                    int a=(int)temp;
                                    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
                                    b.putInt(a  );
                                    byte[] result = b.array();                                      
                                    Log.d("gray value is=", String.valueOf((int)result[1]));
                                //  Log.d("gray value is=", String.valueOf(getLastBytes(a)));
                            }
                        }
```

Here result[1] should correspond to the 'R' value. So how is it negative?

Comment: Check the size of result variable ,Grayscale doesnot have RGB  its only 2 dimensional

Comment: @Nadosh How will that help?

Comment: @Nadosh You misinterpreted that ... in terms of storage in grayscale in android, there are 8 fields..the grayscale images have equal R,G,B bytes in terms of storage. For eg. temp has values like 133585214

Comment: Grayscale is 2 dimensional youu cant get r,g,b ;also check value of 'a' itself

Comment: @Nadosh You please read about it. The value of a is very large which is the equivalent decimal representation of the hex value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
        long temp=bb.getPixel(i, j);
        R = Color.red(temp);
        G = Color.green(temp);
        B = Color.blue(temp);
```

Comment: Thanx !! This was just so simple with this :)

Answer (score 2):

It is because of all type changes, the casting associated with it, and the fact that those types are signed.

First of all, the initial return value of `getPixel()` is an `int` (32-bits or 4 bytes, one byte for ARGB).  Placing it into a long seems unnecessary here, because you just cast it back into an `int`.  But so far so good.

When you get the byte array, you are correct that the four bytes for ARGB are in order so `result[1]` should be the Red value.  However, when you implicitly cast that byte into an int in your log statement, a problem happens.

Because the `int` is four bytes long, and both `int` and `byte` are signed types, sign extension applies to the result, i.e.

- The byte 0x48 will extend into an int as 0x00000048
- The byte 0x88 will extend into an int as 0xFFFFFF88

So when you print the result to the log, it interprets the decimal value of your data to be a negative number.  Admittedly, even if you didn't cast and just printed the value of `byte`, that type is still signed (i.e. it goes from -128 to 127 and not 0 to 255, and 0x88 means -120), so the log output would be the same.

If you want to log out the actual 0-255 value, modify your code to bitmask the pixel data to defeat sign extension in the `int`:

```
int red = (int)(result[1] & 0xFF);
Log.d("gray value is=", String.valueOf(red));
```